# How to get value on Datepicker in Edit view (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Im working on my school ASP.NET MVC project. I want to edit information about user. When i call edit action, controller return model in to Edit View, and i want to see the value on the datepicker.

```
  <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Datum rođenja", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="Model.DatumRodjenja" name="DatumRodjenja" class="form-control datepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="entypo-calendar"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I don't use `@Html.TextBoxFor`, what should i do to see value od date in datepicker? How can i use `@Html.TextBoxFor` in this code to Datepicker works fine?

Comment: Is `DatumRodjenja` your `DateTime` property? - If so then its `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatumRodjenja, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })`

Comment: That's help, tnx you :)

Answer (score 0):

use same name of input type as your model name and value field for getting value  in edit mode.

```
  <input type="date" name="Trandate" value="@Model.Trandate" />
```

Hope this work for you.